# Extracting sorted array values satisfying range criteria in react UI

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

- I filtered the array values with the user input values from drop down box , check box and text boxes
- I am trying to sort the filtered array values
- Followed by rendering the name properties along with sports games and grade which grades belonging to certain range
- I have used array.filter() method and conditional rendering for execution
- I am struck with conditional operation of filtering sport_games grades as well as rendering filtered values
  value to be displayed are name with sports games and grade passing satisfying range criteria
- can you guys help me to solve the issue with your suggestions
- Entire code is available in the stackblitz link:https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-geum6v?file=index.js
- providing the code snippet below:

index.js (html part)

```
    Players Belonging to same zip code:
         <input type="text" name="zip_code" defaultValue={zip1} onChange={this.handleChange_zip}></input> <br />

          Number of male over certain age: <input type="number" name="age_number" defaultValue= {age1} onChange={this.handleChange_age}></input> <br />

          Students not Belonging from a given state: 
          <select value={state1} onChange={this.handleChange_state}>
            <option value="select">Select</option>
            <option value="CA">CA</option>
            <option value="TX">TX</option>
          </select><br/>

          List of Subjects received grades: <input type="checkbox" name="subjects" value={check} onChange={this.handleChange_sub}></input><br/>

Students received a grade within a range: 
          min grade:<select value={min_grade} onChange={this.handleChange_mingrade}>
            <option value="select">Select</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="c">C</option>
          </select>
          max_grade:<select value={max_grade} onChange={this.handleChange_maxgrade}>
            <option value="select">Select</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="c">C</option>
          </select><br/><br />

          <button onClick={this.sportsZipSearch.bind(this)}>Submit</button><br />
          {zipValue && <Zip result={result} />}

Players with range of Sport games grades : {result.length && result[0].Sports_games.map(g => { var visibility = (check && g[Object.keys(g)[0]]) ? 'block' : 'none'; var sorted = {sorted:(visibility && g[Object.keys(g)[0]])}; console.log(sorted);return <div style={{display: visibility}}>{Object.keys(g)[0]} {g[Object.keys(g)[0]]}</div> } )} <br/><br/>
```

(JS part)

```
sportsZipSearch = () => {
const { zip1, dob1, age1, state1, check, count } = this.state;

const newArray = students.filter((el) => { return ((el.zip === zip1) && (parseInt(el.Age) <= parseInt(age1[Object.keys(age1)[0]])) && (el.sports_state != (state1)) && check ) });
const newArray1 = newArray[0].Sports_games.map((el1) => { return Object.keys(el1) });
const sorted = newArray1[Object.keys(newArray1)].sort();
console.log(age1);
console.log(zip1);
console.log("here--", this.state.zip1, this.state.age1);
console.log(newArray);
//console.log(newArray1);
//console.log(sorted);
console.log(newArray.Subjects);
console.log(count);
this.setState({ result: newArray, zipValue: true })
```

}

zip.js

```
const Zip = (props) => {
  return(
    props.result.map(
      results => 
      <h1 key={results.player_first_name}>{results.player_first_name}</h1>
      /* This is not a perfect key, but given the values at hand */
      )
  )
}
```

Comment: Does your `sportsZipSearch` function work as expected?

Comment: Thanks for your reply...sportsZipSearch function works as expected