# Calculate age from date of birth user input value in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to fetch user input date of birth value and convert to its equivalent age.

In the console showing the fetched value, but its not assigned to state variable `dob1`, struck with age calculation function execution.

The entire code is available in the stackblitz and it's link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-geum6v?file=index.js

HTML

```
Number of male over certain age: <input type="date" name="date_of_birth" defaultValue= {dob1} onChange={this.handleChange_age}></input> <br /><br />
```

JS

```
handleChange_age = (event) => {
    console.log("DOB:", event.target.value);

    this.setState({ dob1: event.target.value })
    console.log(this.state.dob1);
    var age_latest = {age_latest: this.calculate_age}
    console.log(age_latest);

    this.setState({ age1: age_latest })
    console.log("Age:", this.state.age1);
  }

calculate_age = (dob1) => {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(this.state.dob1);
    var age_now = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) 
    {
        age_now--;
    }
    console.log(age_now);
    return age_now;
  }
```

Comment: I would recommend to use momentJS. It's perfectly working for your scenario.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, `setState` is asynchronous in nature. So if you want to have the newly set `state`'s value to do something, use the [callback argument of setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Secondly, `calculate_age` takes a `dob` argument. You can use that directly inside your `handleChange_age` function.

Here is the modified code.

Your `calculate_age` function uses `dob1` argument instead of `this.state.dob1`:

```
calculate_age = (dob1) => {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dob1);  // create a date object directly from `dob1` argument
    var age_now = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) 
    {
        age_now--;
    }
    console.log(age_now);
    return age_now;
  }
```

Your `handleChange_age` now calls `this.calculate_age` with `event.target.value`:

```
handleChange_age = (event) => {
    console.log("DOB:", event.target.value);

    this.setState({ dob1: event.target.value }, () => {
      // example of setState callback
      // this will have the latest this.state.dob1
      console.log(this.state.dob1);
    })

    // call calculate_age with event.target.value
    var age_latest = {age_latest: this.calculate_age(event.target.value)}
    console.log(age_latest);

    this.setState({ age1: age_latest }, () => {
      // this will have the latest this.state.age1
      console.log("Age:", this.state.age1);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help...the code is working...also can you able to provide your suggestion for the other problem where given link below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55192426/extracting-sorted-array-values-satisfying-range-criteria-in-react-ui

Comment: Sure, I will look into it :) If this solution worked for you please [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: hey I accepted...can you help me with the other question stoo

Answer (score 1):

Another `calculate_age` for some reason mehamasum's function is not working for me

```
const calculate_age = dob => {
  const birthDate = new Date(dob); 
  const difference = Date.now() - birthDate.getTime();
  const age = new Date(difference);

  return Math.abs(age.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}
```